# update values of only certain rows in dataset1, with values from dataset2 in R - but only the ones that don't match, or else keep the original?

Tags: r, join, dataframe, merge

So, I have two dataframes, original and the one made from extracted rows of the original and then changed values in one of the columns.

They both have same no. of columns (10), but the original is bigger than the second one. Type of data is the same in both, and I need to replace values in one column which is made of factors. I've tried left_join and merge but I run into errors, which is probably my mistake, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong as I still don't understand R properly.

eg. dataframe 1:

1. ALB  Med
2. SKJ  Eq
3. ALB  Gyre
4. BUM  Eq
5. WHM  Trans
6. YFT  Eq

dataframe 2:

3. ALB  North Atl
4. BUM  South Atl
5. WHM  Gyre
6. YFT  Gyre

hat I want to get:

1. ALB  Med
2. SKJ  Eq
3. ALB  North Atl
4. BUM  South Atl
5. WHM  Gyre
6. YFT  Gyre

Excerpt of original data from R (dataset1):

```
    > print(catchesbyPPOW[1:10,])
   Species  Long   Lat tCatch_sqrt        ECOREGION                   REALM          PROVINC TYPE
1      ALB  17.5 -57.5   0.5099020             <NA>     Southern Cold Water        Antarctic PPOW
2      YFT  17.5 -57.5   0.2812472             <NA>     Southern Cold Water        Antarctic PPOW
3      BFT -67.5 -52.5   2.9238673 Patagonian Shelf Temperate South America       Magellanic MEOW
4      BFT -62.5 -52.5   3.2256782             <NA>     Atlantic Warm Water Malvinas Current PPOW
5      ALB -52.5 -52.5   0.2323575             <NA>     Southern Cold Water     Subantarctic PPOW
6      SWO -52.5 -52.5   0.9996549             <NA>     Southern Cold Water     Subantarctic PPOW
7      ALB -32.5 -52.5   0.4097926             <NA>     Southern Cold Water        Antarctic PPOW
8      BET -32.5 -52.5   1.4336387             <NA>     Southern Cold Water        Antarctic PPOW
9      SWO -32.5 -52.5   1.2541730             <NA>     Southern Cold Water        Antarctic PPOW
10     YFT -32.5 -52.5   1.2215236             <NA>     Southern Cold Water        Antarctic PPOW
                BIOME optional
1               Polar     TRUE
2               Polar     TRUE
3                <NA>     TRUE
4  Boundary - western     TRUE
5               Polar     TRUE
6               Polar     TRUE
7               Polar     TRUE
8               Polar     TRUE
9               Polar     TRUE
10              Polar     TRUE
```

Dataset 2:

```
> print(outliers[1:10,])
    Species  Long   Lat tCatch_sqrt                  ECOREGION                   REALM TYPE BIOME optional
3       BFT -67.5 -52.5   2.9238673           Patagonian Shelf Temperate South America MEOW  <NA>     TRUE
39      SWO -62.5 -42.5   0.6316645     North Patagonian Gulfs Temperate South America MEOW  <NA>     TRUE
130     ALB -57.5 -37.5   7.6342489 Uruguay-Buenos Aires Shelf Temperate South America MEOW  <NA>     TRUE
131     BET -57.5 -37.5   0.8367258 Uruguay-Buenos Aires Shelf Temperate South America MEOW  <NA>     TRUE
132     BUM -57.5 -37.5   0.5127475 Uruguay-Buenos Aires Shelf Temperate South America MEOW  <NA>     TRUE
133     SAI -57.5 -37.5   1.3915028 Uruguay-Buenos Aires Shelf Temperate South America MEOW  <NA>     TRUE
134     SKJ -57.5 -37.5   1.2453915 Uruguay-Buenos Aires Shelf Temperate South America MEOW  <NA>     TRUE
135     SWO -57.5 -37.5   2.4453357 Uruguay-Buenos Aires Shelf Temperate South America MEOW  <NA>     TRUE
136     WHM -57.5 -37.5   0.2320991 Uruguay-Buenos Aires Shelf Temperate South America MEOW  <NA>     TRUE
137     YFT -57.5 -37.5   2.2360680 Uruguay-Buenos Aires Shelf Temperate South America MEOW  <NA>     TRUE
             PROVINC
3   Malvinas Current
39  Malvinas Current
130 Malvinas Current
131 Malvinas Current
132 Malvinas Current
133 Malvinas Current
134 Malvinas Current
135 Malvinas Current
136 Malvinas Current
137 Malvinas Current
```

I deleted my failed attempts, I just have the latest one I tried with left_join:

```
PPOWoutliers<-left_join(catchesbyPPOW, outliers, by = NULL)
```

Which gave me this warning:

```
Joining, by = c("Species", "Long", "Lat", "tCatch_sqrt", "ECOREGION", "REALM", "PROVINC", "TYPE", "BIOME", "optional")
Warning message:
In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```

Comment: Can you provide data in an easy-to-paste form? What have you tried and doesn't appear to work?

Comment: HI @RomanLuštrik I just updated the description, hope it helps!

Comment: Note that the columns in your datasets don't seem to be the same (as you suggest they are in the text)

Comment: The order might be of but the names should be the same, what am I missing?

Comment: `BIOME` and `optional` are not in second dataset

Answer (score 0):

EDITED to reflect that you may not have the same columns on both data sets

Merge doesn't take into account row names.

Try this:

```
columns_to_replace <- c("ECOREGION","REALM","TYPE")
dfnew <- df1
dfnew[as.numeric(rownames(df2)),columns_to_replace] <- df2[,columns_to_replace]
```

or this if you have the same columns on both datasets:

```
dfnew[as.numeric(rownames(df2)),] <- df2
```

Comment: as noted by @Miff in the question comments, it can't work if your columns are different in both datasets, what fields exactly do you want to replace ?

Comment: I want to replace values in column PROVINC with new values from outliers dataset, where the two differ, or else keep the original value. Columns shoud be the same, the order is different because column PROVINC was moved in the second one as I updated the values.

Comment: I edited my code to reflect that, you can put any column name in the `columns_to_replace` variable

Comment: Thank you... I tried both approaches, but with both I get this: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: When these `data.frames` are built, probably using `as.data.frame` or `read.csv` etc, add the parameter `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: Thanks! I think that might have been a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for help! 
I found a way, in the end.
I did a left_join of the datasets with the variable I wanted to change with a different name in dataset2. Then I did a for loop to replace all the resulting NA's with values from the original column, and it worked.

```
library(dplyr)

PPOWoutliers <-left_join(catchesbyPPOW, outliers, by = NULL)
summary(PPOWoutliers)

for (i in 1:2448){
   if (is.na(PPOWoutliers[i,11])==TRUE){
     PPOWoutliers[i,12] <- as.character(PPOWoutliers[i,7])}
  else{
    PPOWoutliers[i,12] <- as.character(PPOWoutliers[i,11])}
  }
```